# Insert characters into entire row and union with continue of row_number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, union, sum

I have first query

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp1
select 
    IDX=ROW_NUMBER() over(order by A_ID)
    ,A = A_ID
    ,Number = COUNT(*)
    ,Value = sum(ammount)
into #tmp1
from #t
group by A_ID
```

Need to do union with

```
   select   
    IDX  = ''
    ,A = 'Total'
    ,SUM (Number)
    ,SUM(Value)
   from #tmp1
```

After UNION ALL I get dataset:

```
+--------+------------+-------------+--------+
|  IDX   |     A      |  Number     |  Value |
+--------+------------+-------------+--------+
|      1 |  PCX       |      12     |  22.00 |
|      2 |  TOC       |       3     |  89.00 |
|      0 | Total      |      15     | 111.00 |
+--------+------------+-------------+--------+
```

But I need:

```
    +--------+------------+-------------+--------+
    |  IDX   |     A      |  Number     |  Value |
    +--------+------------+-------------+--------+
    |      1 |  PCX       |      12     |  22.00 |
    |      2 |  TOC       |       3     |  89.00 |
    |============================================|
    |      3 | Total      |      15     | 111.00 |
    +--------+------------+-------------+--------+
```

How to insert entire row of '=' and continue row number of IDX ?

Version is 2014 Enterprise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` and the `GROUPING()` function:

```
SELECT 
    idx = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GROUPING(a_id), a_id),
    a = CASE WHEN GROUPING(a_id) = 0 THEN a_id ELSE 'Total' END, 
    number = COUNT(*),
    value = SUM(amount)
FROM #t
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((a_id), ()) 
ORDER BY idx ;
```

In older versions (that don't have `GROUPING SETS`) you could use `ROLLUP` instead. In even older versions (or any version if you prefer a simpler query), you could split the query into 2 parts and `UNION ALL` with:

```
SELECT 
    idx = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (a_id),
    a = a_id, 
    number = COUNT(*),
    value = SUM(amount)
FROM #t
GROUP BY a_id

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    1 + COUNT(DISTINCT a_id),
    a_id, 
    COUNT(*),
    SUM(amount)
FROM #t

ORDER BY idx ;
```

Tested at [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/DLGE17051)